# Identifying a plant seen in Cyprus

Tags: plant-identification

This plant was seen in Cyprus a few days ago and my girlfriend was wondering what it is.

Is anyone able to identify it please?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I believe you might have already identified this plant but in future, if you or anyone reading this thread wants to identify any plant, flowers or tree can go to [Whatistheplant.com](https://whatistheplant.com/) and you'll be amazed with the results in seconds. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be [Carissa Macrocarpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carissa_macrocarpa), commonly known as Natal plum, or another related species. If one searches for common plants in Cyprus, it does come up easily. I am guessing that the climate in Cyprus is very similar to its native south african Eastern Cape and that's why it's been introduced as a landscaping plant.

But just as with the introduced and now invasive [giant hogweed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heracleum_mantegazzianum) it is somewhat of a hazard, although to a much lesser degree, as the whole plant is poisonous except for the fruit (as long as they are ripe).

**Some of the prominent identifying features:**

- Characteristic spines/thorns
- White flowers
- Large oblong/egg shaped
  fruit
- Glossy leaves

[image]

Comment: Looks right to me. It's not native to Cyprus, but the plant pictured was obviously planted there. Could have been brought in just because it was a pretty plant that worked with the climate.

Comment: It's a plant that tolerates saline wind and the Mediterranean climate isn't that far from the South African Cape climate so I'm entirely sure this plant could thrive there.

Comment: You might get more upvotes with pictures.

Comment: That does look very similar. As you say the flowers, plums and leaf shapes all match.

Comment: My girlfriend says "That describes this plant exactly! Thank you! X"